# Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) and tight coupling?

Tags: javascript, architecture, dojo, google-closure, js-amd

So I have been reading up on the CommonJs Modules spec and looking at the dojo implementation and google closure implementation.  The concept is pretty cool but I had the question of tight coupling of your application using AMD.

Example from closure site:

```
goog.provide('tutorial.notepad');
goog.provide('tutorial.notepad.Note');

goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('goog.ui.Zippy');

/**
 * Iterates over a list of note data objects, creates a Note instance
 * for each one, and tells the instance to build its DOM structure.
 */
tutorial.notepad.makeNotes = function(data, noteContainer) {
  var notes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var note = 
      new tutorial.notepad.Note(data[i].title, data[i].content, noteContainer);
    notes.push(note);
    note.makeNoteDom();
  }
  return notes;
};

/**
 * Manages the data and interface for a single note.
 */
tutorial.notepad.Note = function(title, content, noteContainer) {
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;
  this.parent = noteContainer;
};

/**
 * Creates the DOM structure for the note and adds it to the document.
 */
tutorial.notepad.Note.prototype.makeNoteDom = function() {
  // Create DOM structure to represent the note.
  this.headerElement = goog.dom.createDom('div',
      {'style': 'background-color:#EEE'}, this.title);
  this.contentElement = goog.dom.createDom('div', null, this.content);
  var newNote = goog.dom.createDom('div', null,
      this.headerElement, this.contentElement);

  // Add the note's DOM structure to the document.
  goog.dom.appendChild(this.parent, newNote);
  return new goog.ui.Zippy(this.headerElement, this.contentElement);
};
```

So my question isn't there tight coupling occurring here?  If you provide tutorial.notepad to the application and some other module requires it and functionality changes within tutorial.notepad isn't there a tight coupling problem here.  Basically you are chaining together modules that should be able to live on there own thus creating a fragile architecture.

I could be thinking about this wrong, if anyone can talk about this in an architecture context that would be appreciated or any resources about architecting a loosely coupled AMD architecture.

Comment: Well, Closure is **NOT** AMD-style.  As you mentioned, Closure **is** tightly-coupled.  It does **NOT** use AMD.  Therefore, the Closure Library is designed to be "modular" (similar to Dojo) but not "loose-coupling".  Dojo from 1.6 onwards will be AMD-style loosely-coupled, although it will continue to have a global "dojo" object for backwards compatibility until 2.0.

Comment: Gotcha.  Is there any place I can read about how dojo is planning to implement AMD-style and loosely coupled?

Comment: Start with documentation on the Dojo site, then you'll need to subscribe to the developers' mailing list -- that where up-coming verions are discussed.